# Make menu link expand instead of redirect

Tags: theming, navigation

Let's say that I have a following menu:

- A

  - A1
  - A2
- B

Which looks like this:

[image]

When somebody clicks on the arrow on the right of *A* (or in the empty space on the left of the arrow) the submenu expands, but when they click on *A* it redirects to the page set in `admin/structure/menu/item/785/edit`.

I want *A* to also expand the submenu instead of redirecting. How do I achieve that in Drupal 7?